# Installing composer package inside laravel that has dependency in laravel componenets

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am installing a package inside laravel project.
The package has the following dependencies:

```
"require": {
    "illuminate/database": "^5.6",
    "tightenco/collect": "^5.6"
}
```

If I install the package in a fresh composer project it works perfectly.

this is the errors i get.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.39
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.35
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.5.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.3
    - Installation request for avifatal/sql-schema-diff dev-master -> satisfiable by avifatal/sql-schema-diff[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.1
    - avifatal/sql-schema-diff dev-master requires illuminate/database ^5.6 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.2, v5.6.3, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9].
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.25, v5.5.26, v5.5.27, v5.5.28, v5.5.29, v5.5.3, v5.5.30, v5.5.31, v5.5.32, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.38, v5.5.39, v5.5.4, v5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9].
```

Comment: set "laravel/framework": "5.6.*" in require section of composer.json file and than run composer update.

Comment: @parthu_panther can you please explain why? isn't the hole idea behind decoupling `illuminate/database` that it does not dependent on laravel in anyway?

Comment: this line in your error says so:-  - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.5.34

Comment: @fatnjazzy: Hmm, it's hard to fix it with this package. You can see the conversation in this issue: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7129. As i think you need to try something like remove package `tightenco/collect` and then run `composer require tightenco/collect` So it'll take default fitted version of package with your laravel version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you are trying to add has dependencies which are not supported by your current version of laravel so you need to upgrade your laravel framework version in order to install that package.

Simply set "laravel/framework": "5.6.*" in require section of composer.json file and than run composer update.